# jointure from one to many relation with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I think I'm having a brain freeze or something because I'm pretty sure I did this many times but can't seems to figure it out today :-)

This is a simplification of my problem :

I have 2 tables : Events and Events_tags with a one to many relation :
Events :  *id*, *name*
Events_tags :  *id*, *event-id*, *name*

What I'm looking for, is a query to get every Events that have multiple tags. the number of criteria can be different everytime (0, 1, 2 ...)

---

UPDATE :
I wasn't specific enough.
Data sample :

**Events**

```
  id  |  name 
--------------------
   1  |  concert 1
   2  |  concert 2
   3  |  concert 3
   4  |  concert 4
```

**Events_tags***

```
 id  | event-id  | name
-------------------------
 1   |     1     |  music
 2   |     1     |  live
 3   |     1     |  jazz
 4   |     2     |  music  
 5   |     2     |  live
 6   |     2     |  electronic
 7   |     3     |  music
 8   |     3     |  dj
 9   |     3     |  electronic
 10  |     4     |  music
```

So one query would be for events with tags *music* and *live* (concert 1 & 2) and another for *music* (1 to 4) and a third one for event with the *electronic* tag ( 2 & 3 )

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
   SELECT E.ID, COUNT(*) FROM
   EVENTS E INNER JOIN EVENTS_TAGS ET ON E.ID = ET.EVENT-ID
   GROUP BY E.ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

this shows you all the events associated to more than one tag.
If you could provide us your solution it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: thanx. I wasn't specific enough, I've updated my question

Comment: In this case a better solution would be:
     
          SELECT E.ID, E.NAME  FROM
          EVENTS E INNER JOIN EVENTS_TAGS ET ON E.ID = 
          ET.EVENT-ID WHERE ET.NAME IN ('MUSIC,'LIVE')
          GROUP BY E.ID, E.NAME

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists` :

```
select * 
from Events e
where exists (select 1 from 
              from Events_tags 
              where event-id = e.id
              group by event-id
              having count(*) > 1);
```

Comment: thanx. I wasn't specific enough, I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most efficient method is a simple `group by`:

I would use `exists`, but them most efficient method is probably:

```
select et.event_id
from events_tags et
group by et.event_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

If the event id is sufficient, no `group by` or subquery is necessary.

EDIT:

For your revised query, then you can do almost the same thing.

For instance:

```
select et.event_id
from events_tags et
where et.tag_id in (1, 2)
group by et.id
having count(*) = 2;  -- assumes no duplicate tags on an event
```

The number in the `having` needs to match the size of the list in the `where`.

Comment: thanx. I wasn't specific enough, I've updated my question